# c# class declaration of properties

Tags: c#, class

Is there a way to write this so I don't have to explicitly declare the field `_D`?

- How do I get around the `= new List<T>()` when the class is implemented?

What I have:

```
class c {
    private List<T> _D = new List<T>();
    public List<T> D { get { return _D; } set { _D = value; } }
}
```

What I want:

```
class c {
    public List<T> D { get; set; }
}
```

Wouldn't it be better to declare a constructor to assign the property a `List<T>`?  As in:

```
class c {
    c() { D = new List<t>(); }
    public List<t> D { get; set; }
}
```

What are today's best practices when implementing properties and assigning initial values?

All three are technically correct.  I found the first in a bit of code I'm taking over.  I can't find any purpose behind the original code that declares all the property backing fields. I thought declaring backing fields was not a best practice since c# v3 .. except when you are actually going to use the private field somewhere in the class's methods, which isn't happening here.

You could look at assigning the initial `List<>` to the property as 'Using the property somewhere in the class.'
Or you could look at it as 'Pointless, do it like my third example instead.'

Which is generally regarded as best practice these days?

Comment: Your question is confusing me.  What you want is exactly right, along with declaring initial values in the constructor.  So what **exactly** are you asking?

Comment: `public List<t> D { get; set; } = new List<t>();`?

Comment: Well all three are correct technically.  I found the first in a bit of code I'm taking over.  I'm not finding any purpose behind the original that declares all the properties.  I thought actually declaring properties fell out of best practice since c# v3 .. except when you are actually going to use the private property somewhere in the class's methods.  You could look at assigning the initial List to the property as 'Using the property somewhere in the class.'  Or you could look at it as pointless, do it like my third example instead.  Which is generally regarded as best practice these days?

Comment: You keep misusing the term "property": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Yes the first of the three is because either code you inherited is old, or because the person who wrote it still uses the old method.

I personally use either 2 or both 2 & 3 depending on my needs.

Comment: Get your terms right: What you call properties are called *fields* and what you call attributes are called *properties*.

Comment: @Sach.  Thanks.  You reaffirmed my thinking.  Is there some other syntax for assigning the initial value to `D` I'm forgetting, perhaps without declaring a constructor?

Comment: If the code is old enough, the second method was not available. The auto properties are a newer feature.

Comment: @user5903880 how do you plan on assigning a new instance of `List<T>` to `D` without calling a constructor?

Comment: @user5903880 I think crashmstr's usage is the best way if you want to not declare a field.

Comment: @crashmstr THANKS! @ Sach you too.  That is exactly where I was trying to get to.

Comment: @Jason That depends on the compiler being used to build, not on the code itself.  I'm working in C# v6

Comment: @InBetween you are right.  I'll fix that in the OP shortly.  Or I won;t ... because you just did :-)

Comment: @crushmstr if you want the credit post an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since C# 6 you can do it this way:

```
public IList<int> Prop1 { get; set; } = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: This is simply repeating another user's comment.

Comment: I've not read comments. I can delete the ans if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve the same thing in .NET as well as best practices and recommendations. It all depends on your requirements and responsibilities for the object and properties. I saw a comment with a link to the programming guide which is excellent. These are just a few more examples.

```
public class C<T>
{
    public List<T> D { get; set; } = new List<T>();
}

public class C2
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> D { get; private set; }

    public C2()
    {
        D = new List<int>();
    }
}

public class C3
{
    private List<int> _d = null;

    public List<int> D
    {
        get
        {
            return _d ?? new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```